# How to select one record from database?

Tags: laravel

I want to select from user table name and address columns where  name is John. This query return null. I know in database is user which has name John. I would like to know if this query is property ?

```
 $query = User::where('name', '=', 'John')->select(['name', 'address']);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 $query = User::select('name', 'address')->where('name', '=', 'John')->first();
```

You were not running your query, you need `get()` which returns a collection or `first()` if you want to retrieve a single record.

For your case i think `first()` fits more.

Or following your approach you don't need select in the end but instead:

```
 $query = User::where('name', '=', 'John')->get(['name', 'address']);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use this

```
$query = User::select('name', 'address')->where('name', '=', 'John')->first();
```

Answer (score 0):

Just call `get()` at the end:

```
$query = User::where('name', 'John')->select(['name', 'address'])->get();
```

**Notice: Maybe you're inaccurate in case sensitive. I mean the user name might be "john" not "John"**

Answer (score 0):

You could use `first()`, which does the following:

- limits the results to 1
- get all records
- get the first record from the collection

In the code, you will find:

```php
public function first($columns = ['*'])
{
    return $this->take(1)->get($columns)->first();
}
```

Note that `first()` takes parameter which columns you want to select. So in your case, you can use:

```php
User::where('name', '=', 'John')->first(['name', 'address']);

// Or a prettier solution in my opinion
User::whereName('John')->first(['name', 'address']);
```